# How to use WebView2 to display XML content using XSL transforms?

Tags: xml, wpf, xslt, .net-core, webview2

I'm creating an app in WPF using .Net Core, and need to display authored XML content. We use other software to convert the xml to html for hosting online. However, while authoring I need to be able to see a preview of the local XML content transformed using the xsl file. I'm using Linq to XML.

I started by creating a `WebView2` control in a `TabItem`. Using the the prerelease version 1.0.790, I tried to utilize the `SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping` with no success. I started with just trying to open a generic html file using a copy paste of the example code, but only got a message saying the appassets.example's IP couldn't be resolved. I double checked the location of the folder, and the files in that folder.

My next attempt was to utilize `NavigateToString` and send in the xml. There were a couple issues with this. The first was that any `XProcessingInstruction` get's converted to a comment, which I imagine is a security feature? Without that, all I see is the internal xml content.
The xml gets changed from:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Template-xsl.xsl"?>
```

into a comment:

```
<!--?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Template-xsl.xsl"?-->
```

Another unrelated issue is that if I add an `InternalSubset` the webview doesn't recognize the closing `]>` I wasn't sure if this was a WebView issue, so I checked it in Notepad++ and it looks to be the same issue there. I've tried removing whitespace, and newlines, but nothing changed. The first Entity seems to display ok, but the next line is always a different color which leads me to believe it's somehow reading the end of the first entity as the end DocType. The XML for the DocType is:

```
<!DOCTYPE dmodule [
   <!ENTITY svg-test SYSTEM "svg-test.svg" NDATA svg >
   <!ENTITY svg-test1 SYSTEM "svg-test1.svg" NDATA svg >
]>
```

I started with just creating a string and updating the `InternalSubset`. Then I tried just creating a new document type and inserting that which had the same results as above.

```cs
string ent = Environment.NewLine;

foreach (SVG s in sVGs)
    ent += $"   <!ENTITY {s.GraphicInfoEntityIdent} SYSTEM \u0022{s.FileName}\u0022 NDATA svg >"
        + Environment.NewLine;

XDocumentType doctype = new XDocumentType("dmodule", null, null, ent);
xDoc.AddFirst(doctype);
```

What am I missing, and is this the best approach?

Edit 1: I assumed the browser would just handle the transform, but that clearly isn't the case. Using Martin's suggestion, I've gone back and created a new method to transform the xml prior to passing it to the Webview. This appears to work, but I keep getting a xslt compile error. It didn't give me any indication of why, so I started gutting the xslt scripts and found the culprit. I'll need to figure out how to get the compile to work, as the transform won't completely work without it, but that's another question. The browser will display the transformed xml content.

Comment: Does any WebView component "navigating" to a string that is anything but HTML? I guess your XML is parsed by the HTML5 parser, even if you want to parse the contents as XML. Perhaps you can use `XslCompiledTransform` to transform the XML to HTML and pass that result to the navigate method.

Comment: Have a look at my own question and answer about XML/XSL transformations with the `WebView2` control. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68326542/2287576 There is a command line option that you can use to allow local transformations.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following, you want to

- Locate a local XML file and local XSL file
- Transform XML with XSL to HTML and display the HTML result

I've never had luck with browser transformations, so I have a different solution for you.  Run the transform in your XPF program and message the HTML results to the browser.

1. Use your WPF program to load the XML, XSL and make the transform to HTML.  Since the WPF program is "local", it'll have full visibility on local files.
2. Load a special web page in your WebView2 control.  Post your HTML to the WebView2 window.  Sample below, note script, that catches messages from the XPF program.
3. In your WPF program, post the HTML from step 1, to the special web page.
4. Finally, the .JS catches the message (HTML), and updates the page with it.

Here's the special web page, that listens for the HTML from the XPF program.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='xformhtml'/>
    </body>

    <script type='text/javascript'>

    let xformDiv = document.querySelector( "#xformhtml );

    if( window.chrome.webview ) {
        window.chrome.webview.addEventListener( 'message', event => {
            xformDiv.innerHTML = event.data;
        });
    } else {
        xformDiv.innerHTML = "<h2>Sorry webview communication not supported.</h2>"
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

This link shows how to communicate to and from the sample page.

https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/247

Comment: There is a command line option you can use that will allow local XML transformations with `WebView2`. See my comment to the question which includes the link to my resolution (for C++).

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, that's pretty interesting that you can start WebView2 with access to the local files.  I've got a couple uses for that.  Thanks for posting your comment.  For me, browser transformations have been a weak point (hard to pass parameters, add extension methods, xsl:include other XSL files), and I've had more consistent / debuggable results by doing the transforms with XSLT in System.Xml from C#.

Comment: Yes, there are instances where I also do transformations directly with C#. But in most instances, for the nature of my application and it's XSL transformation requirements, simply displaying the results in the browser is sufficient for me.