# How can you perform a XML / XSL transformation for local files with the WebView2 control?

Tags: xml, xslt, mfc, webview2

Microsoft Edge (and thus the WebView2 control) allows us to navigate to XML files which get transformed into HTML files. But this does not work when the XML file is local to the PC.

I appreciate that we we could potentially create a local web server and use `localhost` but that is a lot of work. The `CHtmlView` control did not have this issue.

---

I noticed a similar question [How to use WebView2 to display XML content using XSL transforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66247063/how-to-use-webview2-to-display-xml-content-using-xsl-transforms) but it was related to WPF. No doubt the same options could be used with the `WebView2` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a discussion on the [`WebView2`](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/1472) GitHub website and a solution was found.

You need to make use of a command line option `--allow-file-access-from-files` which will then allow local XML links to be used. When invoking the Microsoft Edge you just pass it on the command line. But this is how you do it with the `WebView2` control:

```
void CWebBrowser::InitializeWebView()
{
   CloseWebView();

   CString subFolder = GetInstallPath();
   CString appData = GetUserDataFolder();

   auto options = Microsoft::WRL::Make<CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions>();
   CHECK_FAILURE(options->put_AdditionalBrowserArguments(L"--allow-file-access-from-files"));

   HRESULT hr = CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions(
       subFolder,
       appData,
       options.Get(),
       Callback<ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandler>(
           this,
           &CWebBrowser::OnCreateEnvironmentCompleted).Get());

   if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
   {
      CString text;
      if (hr == HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND))
      {
         text = L"Cannot found the WebView2 component.";
      }
      else
      {
         text = L"Cannot create the webview environment.";
      }

      ShowFailure(hr, text);
   }
}
```

The above snippet shows how to use the [`CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2environmentoptions.-ctor?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.864.35) parameter.

Comment: I'm having an issue with creating CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions object.

Error C2065 'CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions': undeclared identifier

What could be the issue? 
Where CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions class is located?

Version:

NuGet packages:
Microsoft.Web.WebView2: 1.0.1083-prerelease
Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary: 1.0.210803.1

Win10 SDK: 10.0.22000.194
WebView2 Runtime: 96.0.1054.62
Framework: Win32 C++
OS: Win10

Comment: Found my problem - needed to include WebView2EnvironmentOptions.h

Comment: @user2995035 Glad you figured it out.